# Evitar un salto de línea

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo este código, en el cual muestra un recuadro de formulario al lado de un texto:

```
<?php
    if($filtro==2)
        $v=$nombre;
    else
        $v="";
?>
<form method="POST" action="mi_foto" novalidate>
    @csrf
        <input style="width: 300px;" id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nombre" placeholder="Buscar tus fotos por nombre" value="{{$v}}">
</form>
<h1 class="text-center text-mute">
```

Y esto me da este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se muestra la caja del formulario y el texto de la etiqueta `<h1>`, pero hay en etre ellos un salto de línea que quiero evitar.
No puedo recurrir a rutas absolutas, ya que a veces al ir a una pagina se incluye un mensaje (ej: El de cuando una fila es introducida en una tabla correctamente) y se superponen.

Comment: esto no es problema de php o html es de css asi que necesitamos ver todo el codigo html para ver como es tu contenedor aunque puedes probar con display:inline-block; , float: left; , display: table-cell; etc...

Comment: @Bryro Dices que con display podria arreglarlo. ¿Y como seria?